# A complex generation of type at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i need to create a `List<T>` type at runtime: i have a string that represents the type of a single item in the list (`T`), and an array of object. 
My question is: how i can obtain the `List<T>`?

I hope I explained myself :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that you want to do it this way? Smells like a design flaw.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
var stringType = Type.GetType("System.String");
var listType = typeof (List<>);
var stringListType = listType.MakeGenericType(stringType);
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(stringListType) as IList;

list.Add("Foo");
list.Add("Bar");
list.Add("Baz");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
Type itemType = Type.GetType("my type name as string");
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
return (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Comment: i've tried this, but my problem is how now i populate da List before return it?

Comment: By casting to IList, you can use Add, Remove and so on.